# Receiving incomplete body with httplib2

Tags: python, httplib2

I am having some trouble using httplib2. 
When I browse to the page with Google Chrome and save the source the file is about 106kB. When I request the file with httplib2 I only get 99.x kB and there is missing a lot of text in the beginning of the file. Is there some kind of size limit on bytes objects? Am I doing something wrong?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.url = 'http://somesite.org'
    self.html = ''
    self.BROWSER = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3'
    self.http = httplib2.Http()
    self.headers = {'Cookie': extract_from_chrome(),
                    'User-Agent': self.BROWSER}
    self.load()

def load(self):
    response, content = self.http.request(self.url, 'PUT', headers=self.headers)
    self.html = content.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Probably no limit. But is it possible Chrome interprets some includes and httplib2 doesn't?

Comment: Why aren't you using `urllib2`?

Comment: @eumiro: I'm condfident that's not the problem.

Comment: @S.Lott: When I started with this project I used urllib2, then I got frustrated because I didn't succeed and tried httplib2 instead. Turns out it was my lack of knowledge of the http-protocol that was the problem, but I had working code with httplib2 so I didn't bother to change back. But now that I have noticed this problem I think I might change back after all.

Comment: Although the question is quite old. Did you trying opening the file in Google Chrome, saving it again and then checking the size. Sounds like some html was dynamically added to the page by JS while loading and hence increased the size.